# Is it possible to check and possibly strip a string if it is binary or not in O(1) time?

Tags: python

Say that a user is able to input anything, and the purpose of the function in question is to make sure it is binary. I know how to do this with an easy loop, but is it possible to do this without a loop?

I have never used the `re` module and I tried looking through the documentation for some guidance, but didn't find anything. Would there be a way to do this with the `str.strip()` function as well?

Just curious if there's a way to do this easily in O1 time.

Comment: What does "binary" mean in this context?

Comment: Do you mean ones and zeros?  e.g.:  `'11000111'`?  Is there a limit to the length?  And no, you can't know if all the characters are 1 or 0 without looking at each one.

Comment: Any attempt to determine whether a string contains only binary digits will have to inspect each character in the string, so it logically cannot be O(1) - it must increase with the length of the input.

Comment: Sorry, yes binary in this case means '101010011'

Comment: @simplycoding By stripping, you mean strinpping anything other than 0 and 1?

Comment: Unless you assume binary string is in form of `'0b...'`.

Answer (score 2):

The somewhat pythonic way to do this is:

```
def is_binary(s):
    try:
        # To int from base 2
        from_binary = int(s.strip(), 2)
    except ValueError:
        # Wasn't binary
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I wouldn't worry about optimizing.  If you want something fast, pythons probably not your best bet :D [Also the best you're going to get is O(N) because you need to look at the whole string regardless]

Comment: Thanks. I just want to do this old problem in Python, so I'm not looking to implement this in any other language

Comment: I think the `else` can be removed. just put the `return True` in the lastest line or in the `try:` block after `from_binary = int(s.strip(), 2)` :)

Comment: @atupal: Sure the `else` is extra, I included it because it seems more semantically correct :D

Comment: If we are being picky, you probably don't need to assign to `from_binary` since it's not used - you are only using `int` for the side effect that it throws an exception when the input is not convertable.  That's just a personal preference, though.

Answer (score 0):

By stripping, if you meant removing all the other characters exception 0, 1, you can use regular expression like this

```
import re
binary = re.compile("[01]+")

def getBinary(inputString):
    tString = "".join(binary.findall(inputString))
    return len(tString) == len(inputString), tString
```

**Sample Runs:**

```
print getBinary("abcd12340001")    # (False, '10001')
print getBinary("11111")           # (True, '11111')
print getBinary("00000")           # (True, '00000')
print getBinary("01010101")        # (True, '01010101')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bstring = "1101"
import re
if re.match("^[01]+$",bstring): 
  print "Binary"
else: 
  print "Not binary"
```

You can use regular expression to find out if the string is binary or not.